# Как Java может получить данные из другой программы, например, из калькулятора?

Tags: java

В Windows 10 запущен калькулятор, в нем появилось число 4. Вопрос, как можно с помощью средств Java языка получить эти данные? Эту четверку? Я правильно понимаю, что этого никак не сделать?

[image: калькулятор]

Comment: сделать можно, но не одними только средствами Java если с помощью WinAPI удасться докопаться до содержимого, но тип приложения может помешать — с 10кой вышел новый тип приложений (универсальный UWP) там все немного уже не WinAPI насколько я помню

Comment: разве что очень извращенными методами. Поле "ответ" в современном Калькуляторе не представляет из себя отдельное окно с точки зрения WinAPI. Вообще - весь калькулятор это одно окно класса `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow`. Все кнопочки и "поля ввода" - нарисованы на нем. Поэтому стандартные способы нахождения нужного окна и копирования его текстового содержимого тут не применимы. Даже на нативных языках а-ля C++ это будет очень большой проблемой